# Using append to insert ID and have sound play

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I'm in the early works of trying to add a favorites list to a soundboard (I've already got the localstorage stuff to work). The way I have the audio work is it gets the ID from the button pressed and adds .mp3 to it then plays it, which works. I have code where when you press a button it takes its ID and creates another button, inserting that ID into it which should play the sound the same way the other buttons do, but it doesn't. Any ideas? The code is literally the same, but just doesn't seem to play a sound when .append creates the button.

relevant favorite.js Javascript

```js
//audio
var audios = Array.prototype.map.call(
  document.getElementsByName("names"),
  function(el) {
    var audio = new Audio();
    var src = "mp3/" + el.id + ".mp3";
    el.onclick = function() {
      audio.src = src;
      audio.play();
    };
    return audio;
  });

//favorited sound
function reply_click(clicked_id) {
  alert("Added to Favorites");
  $('#add').append('<span><a href="#/" id="' + clicked_id + '" name="names" class="buttonsf">Sound1</a></span>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#/" id="Sound1" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Sound1</a>
</div>
<div id="add">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="favorite.js"></script>
```

Comment: The first value of `onclick` is an event, you can't pass an id to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value passed to the click event should take an `Event`

so, changing `onclick="reply_click(this.id)"` to `onclick="reply_click(event)"` will pass the event to the function.

Then changing the function parameter from `clicked_id` to `e` (or what ever you want it to be called signifying that it is an event) you can access the id by using `e.currentTarget.id` and inserting that.

Se my example below:

```js
//audio

function playAudio(e) {
  let el = e.currentTarget
  var audio = new Audio();
  var src = "mp3/" + el.id + ".mp3";
  audio.src = src;
  audio.play();
  return audio;
}

function createListeners() {
  let names = document.getElementsByName("names")
  for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    let name = names[i]
    name.removeEventListener('click', playAudio)
    name.addEventListener('click', playAudio)
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  createListeners()
})

//favorited sound
function reply_click(e) {
  alert("Added to Favorites");
  $('#add').append('<span><a href="#/" id="' + e.currentTarget.id + '" name="names" class="buttonsf">Sound1</a></span>');
  createListeners()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#/" id="Sound1" onClick="reply_click(event)">Sound1</a>
</div>
<div id="add">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="favorite.js"></script>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. I added a page to my website if you'd like to look at it https://www.randommemes.website/open.html it uses the code you gave. If you inspect element after the "click to add to favorites" is pressed you can see both the two bottom buttons have the same exact code but only the first works

Comment: When I click the link it creates this: `<span><a href="#/" id="DoodleBob" name="names" class="buttonsf">This was made with .append and doesnt work</a></span>` Is that the correct output?

Comment: Yes, and the one that does works is the exact same thing.

Comment: When the other one is clicked it plays a sound. When the one that is created is clicked it doesn't play a sound.

Comment: You are not attaching a click event to that newly created link

Comment: I don't think I understand what that would be for. If it's to get the audio, that should be detected from name="names".

Comment: That only runs once, if you add a new element it doesn't detect that it was added and doesn't add the event to the newly created item

Comment: ayyyyyyyy, that worked!! I appreciate the help, man. Thank you so much!